# Print function and dataframe view/copy

Tags: python, pandas

If I use the code 1 below, I get the following error:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

while I do not get it if I use the code 2.

Both of the code should create a copy, why does the print function change this?

**code 1**

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
df    

def f(df_par):
    df_par.iloc[0, 0] = 8

mask = df.iloc[:, 0] > 1
df = df.loc[mask,:]
f(df)
```

**code 2**

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
print(df)

def f(df_par):
    df_par.iloc[0, 0] = 8

mask = df.iloc[:, 0] > 1
df = df.loc[mask,:]
f(df)
```

Comment: Please mark the correct answer if it answered your question!

Answer (score 0):

First, this is a warning not an error. But, it is there for a reason and should not be ignored!

As explained [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing), this warning happens because it is hard to predict whether or not one of your lines will be making a copy of the dataframe or just getting a view of it (deep vs shallow copy).

This is the line in question:

```
df = df.loc[mask,:]
```

Your print operation is not actually changing anything. This line is still *probably* creating a copy after print is run. In this case, we know it is definitely creating a copy, which we know because of the warning, but this might not always be the case, hence the warning.

The difference is in the code that detects this problem. There must be something that needs to happen for this issue to be detected which does not after print() is called.

To resolve this, just change the line to this to ensure you and your code knows that you are creating a copy:

```py
df = (df.loc[mask,:]).copy()
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible that the same code executed different times can generate or not generate the warning? If this is true is it safer create a deep copy every time you have to modify a dataframe?

Comment: Yes, the same code can cause the warning to not be shown after the first time it was displayed to the user. You should create a deep copy when you want to create a deep copy. Sometimes you just want to change the original. This warning is for those cases where the code doesn’t know which of these two will happen. You should just make sure you do not write code that can cause this warning, more details can be seen here: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/